# Gerrit Code Review behind reverse proxy

Tags: apache, gerrit

I have an instance of Gerrit Code Review that I setup behind a reverse proxy. The configuration file for this is:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://my-host:8090/
[database]
    type = postgresql
    hostname = db-host
    database = reviewdb
    username = gerrit2
[index]
    type = LUCENE
[auth]
    type = HTTP
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = gerrit2
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://my-host:9090/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

Then, I tried to configure an Apache VirtualHost with authentication to pass along to gerrit, using an existing digest I have. The following is the conf file of the VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
  ServerName my-host

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Location /login/>
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "bloodhound"
    AuthDigestDomain /bloodhound
    AuthUserFile /opt/bloodhound/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest
    Require valid-user
  </Location>

  AllowEncodedSlashes On
  ProxyPass / http://my-host:8090/

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I try to access `http://my-host:9090/login` I get an error page from Gerrit Code Review says:

```
Configuration Error

Check the HTTP server's authentication settings.

The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.

If the HTTP server is Apache HTTPd, check the proxy configuration includes an authorization directive with the proper location, ensuring it ends with '/':
```

It's not clear to me why the authentication information is not being sent (actually, a login window does not even appear for crediential input). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the port numbers in `gerrit.config`. Change them as follows to match your proxy config:

```
[gerrit]
    canonicalWebUrl = http://my-host:9090/

[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://my-host:8090/
```

The `listenUrl` should also be specified using `localhost` to prevent authentication bypass.

Comment: When I swap the port numbers and try to access my-host:9090, I get a connection refused error. Before, at least, I was getting the Gerrit Code Review error page, which led me to believe at least the proxy part was setup correctly.

Comment: Did you stop and then again start both services?

Comment: Got it figured out. You were absolutely right, I needed to switch the port numbers. I was able to resolve it when I had a port mis-configuration in my apache setup. Thanks!